# CSS Selectors: Change style of siblings while hover

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
li:hover {
  color: red;
}


/* 
li > li:hover  {
color: blue;
}
 */
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
</ul>
```

If you hover one link, this link should be red, and all other links should be blue. Is it possible to do that with CSS Selectors?

Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try highlighting all `li` to `blue` on hover of `ul` and specific `.link` class `li` gets highlighted to `red`.

```css
.link:hover {
  color: red;
}



ul:hover > li {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='link'>Link 1</li>
  <li class='link'>Link 2</li>
  <li class='link'>Link 3</li>
  <li class='link'>Link 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help. Let me know if so.

```css
ul:hover li {
  color: blue
}

li:hover {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: You sould only use `!important` as a last resort.